# Dynamically handle json response String/array/object using Gson

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, parsing

I am getting dynamic **res_data** value, sometimes it is  array/object/string values from server according to **res_stat** ,so I can't parse this response using Google gson library. 
Different responses are given bellow according to **res_stat**

```
{"res_stat":"S","res_data":[{ sch_name: <NAME_OF_SCHOOL_>
        sch_locat : <SCHOOL_LOATION>
         },]}

{"res_stat”:"E","res_data”:{"res_stat": "E","res_data": {"err_code" :"<ERR_CODE>",
    "err_desc" :"<ERR_DEC>"}}

{"res_stat":"N","res_data":”"}
```

How can i dynamically handle this json response using google gson library? Or any other solutions for this?

Comment: Are you able to add some parameters from the backend in to your response ?

Comment: @DavidJhons I have added some params.

Comment: No, what i meant was, are you able to change  add more fields into  your response ?  Are you able to  add things / change the server API  code ?

Comment: @DavidJhons getting response from client server.. so can't change server code.

Comment: As the "res__stat" parameters is always there ( i assume according to your response) you can try with Pankaj Nimgade's anwser.